# Library not supported

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, xhtml2pdf

I am writing my first app using Python, DJANGO, and the Google Appengine. The basic flow is the user enters data into the db and the creates a report form that gets exported as a PDF.. I have all of it working except the last piece and I am having an issue that I can't find anything on. I have the latest version of the Appengine Launcher, Python 2.7, DJANGO 1.4 and XHTML2PDF 0.0.4. I have it bundled with my application but when I launch my application i get an error on the page and in the log that says:

Fatal error when loading application configuration:

> ```
> Invalid object:
> the library "xhtml2pdf" is not supported
>   in "/Users/username/project/app.yaml", line 31, column 1
> ```

Is there something additional that I need to do or configure or is the a version issue?

Thanks for any help you can give a newbie,

Answer (score 3):

What does line 31 of your `app.yaml` say?

`xhtml2pdf` isn't in the list of [third-party libraries](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27) that App Engine 2.7 supports. (These are libraries that include C extensions, which require extra scrutiny to support. Pure Python libraries are typically O.K.)

Comment: Thanks for the response Dave. Line 31 has - name: xhtml2pdf version: "Latest". All of the tutorials I found for DJANGO include Reportlab and XHTML2PDF. I got the Reportlab in without squawking but it stops me on XHTML2PDF.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to include xhtml2pdf is to drag and drop the xhtml2pdf src folder into the main directory and

from xhtml2pdf import pisa

You also need reportlab, drag and drop works for it too. I had to use a modified version of it from http://ruudhelderman.appspot.com/testpdf but other's have gotten the non-modified version to work.

Answer (score 0):

The xhtml2pdf library is not included in the app engine run time. You can include it yourself, though. The python27 runtime supports the lxml library, which html5lib requires (which is required by xhtml2pdf). However, there is a much simpler solution: use the [conversion api](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/conversion/), which supports HTML -> PDF conversion, and will be much easier to use.